# Problema de novato, el for no recorre toda la lista (python)

Tags: python, bucle-for, condiciones

estoy empezando a programar en python y empecé a jugar con la librería de pytube, tkinter y ffmpeg. Mi problema surge a la hora de querer mejorar el programa para controlar los errores y que no se rompa.

En concreto es con la función "listaVideo()" ya que a la hora de usar la PlayList de la librería pytube hay veces que falla al descargar/encontrar un recurso.

Este problema lo tengo planteado como un for que recorre la lista de videos, si ya existe el archivo pase directamente al siguiente. Y en caso de haber un error del tipo que no se encuentra me gustaria hacer el mismo proceso de saltar al siguiente. El problema me viene en el primer paso:

```
def listaVideo():

   ruta = directorio
   url = link.get()

   lista = Playlist(url)


   x = barra['maximum'] / len(lista.video_urls)


   for video in lista.videos:
    
      if os.path.exists(ruta + "/" + video.title + ".mp4"):
         print("Detectado")
         sumarBarra(x=x)
    
       else:
          # metodo para descargar
```

Lo que intento hacer en la función con la variable x es obtener el porcentaje al que correspondería cada elemento de la lista para una barra de progreso. Inicio el for que recorre mi lista de videos y el problema viene ahora. El if, ya que no se ejecuta para cada elemento de la lista. He tratado de simplificar esta función al máximo quitando el control de excepciones pero nada. Me he quedado bloqueado en este punto y sin saber como implementar el caso en el que de error un elemento de la lista y pasar al siguiente.

Gracias por su tiempo y atención, espero que tenga un buen día.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

si debería pasar por todos los elementos de la lista, aunque alguno o algunos no entren en el `if` y salten en el `else`.

Aquí te pongo un ejemeplo minimalista de lo que interesa hacer:

```
personas = [
    {"nombre": "Pepe", "edad": 14},
    {"nombre": "Ana", "edad": 28},
    {"nombre": "Juan", "edad": 35},
    {"nombre": "María", "edad": 42},
    {"nombre": "Pedro", "edad": 19},
    {"nombre": "Lucía", "edad": 56},
    {"nombre": "Santiago", "edad": 31},
    {"nombre": "Carmen", "edad": 23},
    {"nombre": "Ana", "edad": 12},
    {"nombre": "Jorge", "edad": 47},
    {"nombre": "Laura", "edad": 39},
]

for persona in personas:
    if persona["nombre"] == "Ana":
        print("Ana detectada, tiene " + str(persona["edad"]) + " años")
    else:
        print("no es Ana")
```

Copia, pega, comprueba, modifica y verás como funciona bien.

**¿ que es lo que puede pasar en tu codigo ?**

Bueno, python es muy sencillo pero tambien un poco tontín con las indentaciones, si no esta correctamente indentado petará, on o hará lo que realmente estas buscando.

Por ejemplo, en el codigo que has pegado, **hay un espacio de más** antes de la palabra `else`. Quizás es solo un error a la hora de pegarlo aquí en este foro, pero si resulta que este espacio lo tienes también en tu codigo: **no funcionará**.

```
// Correcto
    if blabla:
        blabla
    else:
        blabla

// Error (fíjate en el espacio de más)
    if blabla:
        blabla
     else:
        blabla
```

Pero bueno, en estos casos suele saltar un error en consola y te da las pistas de que has escrito mal.. (en principio).

Repasa bien esto, a ver si se soluciona.

Si no, vulelve a preguntar por aquí.